# Azure pipelines: Setting and passing the password in powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, passwords, signtool

I am setting the password at the **Library** in the Azure pipelines under a **Variable group**.

Now I want to use the password in one of my powershell script by using its variable name from the **Library** but I am getting error.

```
Write-Host "Signing of Scripts."
Write-Host $PSScriptRoot
If (Test-Path -Path "C:\DigiCerts\*"){
signtool sign /f C:\DigiCerts\Certificate.pfx /t http://timestamp.sectigo.com /fd SHA256 /p $DigicertsPassword C:\dev\package-scripts\scripts\*.ps1
}
Else {
Write-Host "required certificate not found to sign" -ForegroundColor Red
exit 1
}
```

So here I am using `$DigicertsPassword` from the **Library** under **Variable group** which I have stored the password.

****Error:  DigicertsPassword : The term 'DigicertsPassword' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.+ ... tp://timestamp.sectigo.com /fd SHA256 /p "$(DigicertsPassword)" C:\de ...
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: **(DigicertsPassword:String)** [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SignTool Error: Missing filename.****

Comment: use: `"$(DigicertsPassword)"`

Comment: @guiwhatsthat Thanks for the reply, I have used `"$(DigicertsPassword)"` but faced the error, I have edited my question with the error, please check and help

Comment: Did you used the quotes in the code? Without them PowerShell will not interpret them as string.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat Yes as you mentioned I have used it with quotes: `signtool sign /f C:\DigiCerts\Certificate.pfx /t http://timestamp.sectigo.com /fd SHA256 /p "$(DigicertsPassword)"`

Comment: when you simplify your pipeline and only have a script with the code `Write-host "$(DigicertsPassword)"` does this print the value which you have defined in the variable group?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat No its not printing, error logs: **+ Write-host "$(DigicertsPassword)"
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DigicertsPassword:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Comment: Did you link your variable group which contains the variable DigicertsPassword to your pipeline?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat No I think, Do I need to link it in the same `Powershell Script` which is using above for signing? Or how

Comment: Ok, I have got the answer, it should be `$env:variablename will get you the variable value`

Answer (score 1):

As you confirmed, you are using something like below and it can get the value successfully.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  - group: xxx #variable group name
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    DigicertsPassword: $(DigicertsPassword)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "$env:DigicertsPassword"
```

The reason of the issue is secret value need to map, but $key is not a correct way to map.

It has been clarified here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#usage-4

> Secrets are not automatically mapped in

By the way, inline script should be able to get the value of runtime variables.